# Unsupported hash type error while installing hashlib using pip3

Tags: python, pip, hashlib

I am trying to install the hashlib library for Python 3.6.0. Using pip3:

```
pip3 install hashlib
```

I get:

```
Collecting hashlib
  Downloading hashlib-20081119.zip (42kB)
  100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 1.6MB/s
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
        from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filter, filterfalse, map
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
        import email.parser
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/parser.py", line 12, in <module>
        from email.feedparser import FeedParser, BytesFeedParser
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/feedparser.py", line 27, in <module>
        from email._policybase import compat32
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/_policybase.py", line 9, in <module>
        from email.utils import _has_surrogates
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/email/utils.py", line 28, in <module>
        import random
      File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/random.py", line 46, in <module>
        from hashlib import sha512 as _sha512
      File "/private/var/folders/3m/q2pmrqbd2l9154yp_9ww5rjm0000gn/T/pip-build-1upkmzey/hashlib/hashlib.py", line 80
        raise ValueError, "unsupported hash type"
                        ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/3m/q2pmrqbd2l9154yp_9ww5rjm0000gn/T/pip-build-1upkmzey/hashlib/
```

Any idea on how to fix this? I am currently on macOS Sierra 10.12.6, using pip3 9.0.1 and python 3.6.

Comment: `hashlib` module is installed by default. No need to Install it, as you can see it has `python 2.*` coding syntax.

Comment: @Bijoy I encounter the same problem. hashlib is included by default, I can `import hashlib`. But I can’t do `from hashlib import blake2b`.
I know my code is working in two other environements but I have this error just now when trying to run it on a new fresh environnement.
So far I have upgrade pip with `pip3 install --upgrade pip`, and then, trying to install hashlib fails with the same error as OP.
I remember I have to install the hashlib module from pip, because the version which comes in my distro hasn’t this algorithm… Or should I use another ? 'BLAKE2b512', 'BLAKE2s256' ?

Comment: @Bijoy : And my pip installation seems to be fine as I can install some other libs, like paramiko.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As pointed out by [Bijoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5919344/bijoy), there is no need to download the `hashlib` module as it is installed by default.

Simply use `import hashlib` to use it.